# Swiper Slider will start video playing after popup

Tags: popup, html5-video, swiper.js, autoplay, fancybox-3

I am using swiper.js and fancybox v3 to create a popup gallery. One of the slide contain a video, however after I have click and open popup, the video will load and start playing whatever which slide I landed. I have tried to use any events to stop pause the video but it still can't work. Anyone got a solutions?

Here is a codepen example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
        init: false,
        pagination: {
            el: '.swiper-pagination',
            observer: true,
            observeParents: true,
            on: {
                slideChangeTransitionStart: function () {
                    $('.swiper-slide').find('video').each(function () {
                        console.log(this);
                        this.pause();
                    });
                },
                slideChangeTransitionEnd: function () {
                    $('.swiper-slide').find('video').each(function () {
                        this.pause();
                    });
                }
            }
        },
    })
    $('.fancybox-trigger').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var thisTarget = $(this).data('index');
        $.fancybox.open({
            src: "#lightbox",
            type: 'inline',
            opts: {
                toolbar: false,
                defaultType: 'inline',
                autoFocus: true,
                touch: false,
                afterLoad: function () {
                    mySwiper.init();
                    mySwiper.slideTo(thisTarget - 1)
                    $('swiper-slide').find('video').each(function () {
                        this.pause();
                    })
                }
            }
        })
    })
});
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mKOwag?editors=0010

Comment: The first question - why do you use fancybox to display swiper? It totally makes no sense, fancybox already provides swiping capabilities and supports video, too. Are you missing some features?

Comment: Yes, in fact I would like to do something like this: http://idangero.us/swiper/demos/300-thumbs-gallery.html, in a popup. I just removed the thumbs slider in order to simplified the sample, as it is not affecting much of the issue.

Comment: It is possible to get something similar https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/GxBpYY but not the same.

Answer (score 0):

I am not swiper expert, therefore I can not explain why, but I found that callbacks work if you add them like this:

```
mySwiper.on('slideChange', function() { 

  $('.swiper-slide').find('video').each(function() {      
    this.pause();
  });

});
```

Demo - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ERNogR

Comment: Thanks for your reply first. In fact I have tried this event before, however the problem is it can only pause if there is any slide change. When I try to click the first thumb(for example), and the popup and slider will open in first slide, however the video will still play in the back (you can still hear the audio of the video).

Comment: You have to make video elements hidden initially to disable auto-starting on opening first slide.